# share an iscsi target thru samba

Tags: samba, iscsi, openindiana

i just built an Openindiana/Napp-it box and i dont really want to get into Solaris ldap client setup. Does it sound doable to create a linux vm, set up samba on it, then connect to an iscsi target coming from the napp-it box and share it out thru samba?

thanks,

Ron

Comment: Short answer: Yes

Comment: It's called a _NAS Gateway_ and you can find many expensive such devices available from major vendors.

Comment: i started down this road and started seeing max size limitations for a LUN. not sure where to go from here.